# Rock Paper Scissors game using OOP

Tags: java, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I'm a complete beginner to Java and we have just started learning objects and classes in school. I'm trying to create a very simple text-based Rock Paper Scissors game. I do realise that my code is a mess, so I'm asking for some suggestions on how could I improve it and if I'm even in the right direction with OOP.

**Main** class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

**Player** class

```
public abstract class Player {
    private String name;
    private String choice;

    public Player() {}
    public Player(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public void setChoice(String newChoice) {
        choice = newChoice;
    }
    public abstract void selectChoice();
}
```

**User** class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class User extends Player {

    private Scanner input;

    public User() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void selectChoice() {
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: R - Rock, P - Paper, S - Scissors");
        setChoice(input.nextLine().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

**Computer** class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Computer extends Player {

    private Random rand;
    private final int MAX_NUMBER = 3;

    public Computer() {
        setName("Computer");
        rand = new Random();
    }

    public void selectChoice() {
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
        switch(randomNumber) {
            case 0:
                setChoice("ROCK");
                break;
            case 1:
                setChoice("PAPER");
                break;
            case 2:
                setChoice("SCISSORS");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Game** class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    private User p;
    private Computer com;
    private int playerWins;
    private int playerLoses;
    private int ties;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private Scanner scan;

    public Game() {
        p = new User();
        com = new Computer();
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        System.out.println("Please, enter your name:");
        p.setName(scan.nextLine());

        while(isRunning) {
            displayScore();
            p.selectChoice();
            com.selectChoice();
            displayChoices();
            displayWinner(decideWinner());
            updateScore(decideWinner());
            playAgain();
        }
    }

    private void displayScore() {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("Wins: " + playerWins);
        System.out.println("Loses: " + playerLoses);
        System.out.println("Ties: " + ties);
        System.out.println("----------");
    }

    private int decideWinner() {
        // 0 - User wins
        // 1 - Computer wins
        // 2 - tie

        if(p.getChoice().equals("ROCK") && com.getChoice().equals("SCISSORS"))
            return 0;
        else if(p.getChoice().equals("PAPER") && com.getChoice().equals("ROCK"))
            return 0;
        else if(p.getChoice().equals("SCISSORS") && com.getChoice().equals("PAPER"))
            return 0;
        else if(com.getChoice().equals("ROCK") && p.getChoice().equals("SCISSORS"))
            return 1;
        else if(com.getChoice().equals("PAPER") && p.getChoice().equals("ROCK"))
            return 1;
        else if(com.getChoice().equals("SCISSORS") && p.getChoice().equals("PAPER"))
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }

    private void displayChoices() {
        System.out.println("User has selected: " + p.getChoice());
        System.out.println("Computer has selected: " + com.getChoice());
    }

    private void displayWinner(int winner) {
        switch(winner) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("User has won!");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Computer has won!");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("It is a tie!");
        }
    }

    private void playAgain() {
        String choice;
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Enter Yes to play again.");
        choice = scan.nextLine();
        if(!(choice.toUpperCase().equals("YES") ))
            isRunning = false;

    }

    private void updateScore(int winner) {
        if(winner == 0)
            playerWins++;
        else if(winner == 1)
            playerLoses++;
        else if(winner == 2)
            ties++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you expect an OOP approach to solve for you? Design decisions should never be made in a vacuum.

Comment: I suggest you do some validation on the user's input. If the user types anything but the 3 options it always results in a tie now. And you also misleadingly instruct the user to input R, P or S while in fact he needs to type it out

Comment: @jpmc26 come on, it's a programming assignment. You might as well ask what problem is solved by making computer write "Hello world".

Comment: @IMil If it's an assignment, that's even more reason to focus on what the tool is best used for rather than apply it blindly. During coursework is the time you're supposed to be learning. Sadly, our discipline does a *very* poor job in the classroom. It teaches platitudes and incorrect absolutes, leaving new recruits a net cost for employers and struggling to learn the basics on the job instead.

Comment: @jpmc26 I once had a similar assignment. Not in a freshman course, but as part of the hiring process for a senior software developer position that I applied for (with ~20 years of programming experience). You can implement "rock-paper-scissors" with maybe 50 LOC. That's not the point. (I'll probably post my code from back then as part of an answer. I didn't want the job anyhow.)

Comment: @Marco13 It *is* the point. OO is so mistaught and misapplied that we *must* take every opportunity to teach people to think differently about it. I've only found 2 practical purposes for using objects: grouping data and getting late binding of functions. I've also found that these two should typically not be mixed into a single class. This is far and away from what the OP's code shows they have been taught, who has attempted to use objects to create a *taxonomy*. This is **completely** impractical in real life code. If we want people to be competent, we must start tying practices to problems.

Comment: @jpmc26 We could probably argue for a while here, but a guess: "taxonomy" refers to the inheritance in this example? If so: Sure, inheritance is distressingly overused. But it's hard to come up with a "sensible" task/assignment where OOP really matters. In any case, in addition to "grouping data" and "late binding", I'd add **"abstraction"** to the list (i.e. defining an *interface*. One could argue that that's also just an instantiation of "late binding", but that's why I think the space in the comments will not be enough to sort this all out...)

Comment: @Marco13 "But it's hard to come up with a 'sensible' task/assignment where OOP really matters." **Exactly.** This is **exactly** the point. OOP is usually taught so divorced from the actual practical application that no one knows what situations it's actually useful for. If we, as professional developers with years of experience, can't even articulate the problems it's good at solving, how in the world is an inexperienced student supposed to know how to apply it effectively? We need to emphasize the practical *very early* in education, before students develop habits that cause problems.

Comment: @jpmc26 Then on this level: What's wrong with this ("artificial") task where some polymorphism is used via the `Player` class? Again, I think that **abstraction** is something that should be taught (as part of what could more broadly be called "API design"). Could you come up with a more suitable example that could convey the relevant ideas **and** be solved with ~4-5 classes and ~<200 LOC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86960/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-marco13).

Answer (score 19):

Good job so far!

The previous answers already cover a lot, I just want to add this:

### Don't use String for state!

Currently you use `String` to encode the Players `Choice`. This is hard to refactor and it is difficult to add functionality. Prefer its own `Class` or `Enum`.

For example

```
 enum Choice  { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS}
```

Then, you can have a variable containing the choice, for example:

```
 Choice choice = Choice.ROCK;
```

You can add behaviour to the enum:

```
enum Choice  { 
  ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS

  public boolean beats(Choice other)
  {
     switch (this)
     { 
         case ROCK:
              return other == SCISSORS;
         case PAPER:
              return other == ROCK;
         case SCISSORS:
              return other == PAPER;
     }

  }
}
```

Now, your other code can just call `myChoice.beats(otherChoice)`.

Also, you can implement `random()` in the enum, as well as `parseFromUserInput(String s)`. If you do this correctly, you can change the enum, adding different choices, without needing to change any other code in your application.

So, if you want to implement [RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock) , you just extend the `Enum`, and be done!

Also:

### Use Enum instead of magic int values

Instead of returning `int` that encodes the result of the round, use a explicit `enum` as well, replacing the `boolean beats()` method above:

```
enum Result { WIN, LOSS, DRAW }

public Result fights(Choice other)
  {
     switch (this)
     { 
         case ROCK:
              if (other == ROCK)
                   return Result.DRAW
              return other == SCISSORS ? Result.WIN : Result.LOSS;
         ....
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 9):

This code really isn't a mess! While there are a few relatively minor points I can make, your code is generally easy to read and understand, and there's nothing horribly wrong about it.

1. Watch out for user input! I can enter `Z` (or anything but rock/paper/scissors) and the result will always be a tie. You should tell the user when they enter something invalid and have them correct it.
2. Both `Computer` and `Player` use `setName` to set their name - once. I would prefer requiring the use of the `Player` constructor with the `name` parameter since you could then mark `name` as `final`.
3. Why is `setChoice` `public`? It is (and should) only used by `selectChoice`, so mark it `protected`.
4. What happens when I want to play a game between two computer opponents (or two people)? Right now I can't. It would be nice if `Game` let me pass the two `Player` objects in that will be opponents.
5. While I appreciate the `MAX_NUMBER` constant in the `Computer` class instead of just including a magic number, it's a better idea to store your choices in an array and then select a random element of the array.
6. Passing around strings for choices isn't so bad when just dealing with Rock/Paper/Scissors, but it will quickly become unmanagable. [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) were introduced to fix this problem, and generally do a pretty good job of it! It wouldn't hurt to start using them now. Another good spot for an enumeration is in the `decideWinner` method.

   The `Choice` enum type could also provide a method `winsAgainst(Choice other)` that can be used to simplify `decideWinner`.
7. For the most part, your names are great... until we get to `Game` and see `p` and `com`.
8. It would be nice to use the user's name instead of `User` when displaying the winner and when displaying choices.

The following points may directly contradict what your teacher says, as they are more opinion based. Follow whatever your team's (or assignment's) guidelines say.

1. Don't be afraid to include more than one line of code in `main`. If I wrote this program my `main` function would look something like this:

   ```java
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter your name:");

   Player user = new User(scanner.nextLine());
   Player computer = new Computer();
   Game game = new Game(user, computer);

   do {
       game.play();
       System.out.println("Play again? [Yes/No]");
   } while (scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("YES"));
   ```
2. Use braces on all if statements that aren't one line long. I would be fine with `if (winner == 0) playerWins++;`, but `if (winner == 0)\n playerWins++;` is much easier to mess up, especially if you don't have automatic indentation.
3. Don't declare variables before initializing them, if possible. There's no reason to declare `choice` before printing out instructions in the `playAgain` method.

Comment: Enums (or constants) avoid spelling errors. You don't get a clear idea of what's wrong from an error message if you just write "SCISORS" once.

Comment: BTW this part should be emphasized: *Player* computer = new *Computer()*. The OP had them declared as derived types, which is... ok, but inflexible.